# scrapy KeyError: 'Spider not found

Tags: python, ubuntu, scrapy

I wrote this project on my MacBook and it worked fine.But when i upload the project to my linux server that runs ubuntu16, it did't work out.

Here is the error I'm getting

```
2017-02-22 15:09:53 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'Lagou.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['Lagou.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'Lagou', 'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED': True, 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 3}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 142, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 88, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 149, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 57, in run
    self.crawler_process.crawl(spname, **opts.spargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 162, in crawl
    crawler = self.create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 190, in create_crawler
    return self._create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 194, in _create_crawler
    spidercls = self.spider_loader.load(spidercls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 51, in load
    raise KeyError("Spider not found: {}".format(spider_name))
KeyError: 'Spider not found: myspider'
```

---

> ubuntu@VM-76-113-ubuntu:~$ tree

```
-- Lagou
    |-- Lagou
    |   |-- __init__.py
    |   |-- __init__.pyc
    |   |-- items.py
    |   |-- main.py
    |   |-- middlewares.py
    |   |-- pipelines.py
    |   |-- settings.py
    |   |-- settings.pyc
    |   |-- spiders
    |       |-- __init__.py
    |       |-- __init__.pyc
    |       |-- lagou_spider.py
    |       `-- lagou_spider.pyc
    -- scrapy.cfg
```

3 directories, 13 files

---

job_spider.py

```
class LaGouSpider(Spider):
    name = "myspider"
    allowed_domains = ["https://www.lagou.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.lagou.com/zhaopin/"]
```

scrapy.cfg

```
[settings]
default = LagouSpider.settings

[deploy]
#url = http://localhost:6800/
project = LagouSpider
```

---

I sloved this problem by recreate the whole project and reupload it to the server.but i still don't know why it didn't work before, it's the same python environment and the code but it can run on my computer ,rise error on the server

Comment: weird, everything looks fine. Could you post contents of `scrapy.cfg`?

Comment: Not related comment `allowed_domains` should be `allowed_domains = ["lagou.com"]`

Comment: What's the ouput of `scrapy list`?